# Hide Actions menu in Odoo v17

Tags: javascript, menu, odoo, action, hide

> want to hide the actions menu so that user cannot import and export the companies record here is screenshot for version odoov17 community edition what are possible ways to hide this?
> [Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k1R9.png)

Comment: You can set `import` and `export_xlsx` to `"0"` (tree view)

Comment: @Kenly
Thanks for quick response, it works well.